# Is it able to resize the camera screen size using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera

I am using phonegap to develop an android app and writing a photo-taking module.

I have followed phonegap's API and it works (Full screen camera open automatically, snap picture and display in an  tag).

However I would like to resize the camera screen when it open up, that is I do not want the camera screen being full screen, but an small rectangle size which can be put inside some  tag.

I wonder if it is possible, and if yes how would I do it?  Please give me any hints! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap does not control the camera screen. What it does is start the phone's camera app and get the result back, so there's no way you can resize it.

If you want a camera view that does not take all the screen you can either build a phonegap plugin using native code (not sure how to make a plugin only taking part of the screen) or use HTML 5 camera api instead of phonegap's api. The down side is it will only work with recent versions of android.

Have a look at Raymond Camden's blog for a sample of how to use html5 camera api : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap